# Google Drive File Name Automatically Replaced when User download the file

Tags: google-drive-api

[Google Drive Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJNrn.png)

I have one Video file in my Google Drive with the name Perfect.mp4 and I have created a direct download link of this file with Google Drive API. So User can Download this File Without this Warning ( Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses ) but the problem is

when any user downloads this my video file: Perfect.mp4.

Then The name of my video is automatically renamed with the FIELD ID and the file extension is also gone.

This is My Link: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1nRLV1rEcQddkWJ6nGCCdsCvemSp_mqza?alt=media&key=AIzaSyCj8FQUm-Su55PRIQbTZ2BHc9gY8BDr4vE

The filename of my video is correct in my Google Drive account but When Any User Downloads my video file with this link then only The name of my video is automatically renamed with the FIELD ID and the user sees any random file id name instead of my original file name.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`webContentLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads):

> https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1nRLV1rEcQddkWJ6nGCCdsCvemSp_mqza&export=download.

It is not a good idea to share your API key.

Comment: yes but see it when the file size is large then google show it virus scan warning page : https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13N9ajb-Or5GtrZMN9WgiGQaVwzqWf5EO&export=download

Comment: have you tried using the optional query parameter `acknowledgeAbuse=true` ?

Comment: how i use acknowledgeAbuse=true ?

Comment: put `&acknowledgeAbuse=true` at the end of your url

Comment: yes i tried it but it's not working, do you have some idea how to solve this problem

Comment: You could use deploy a web app and have it serve your file. I don't believe you can skip the malware verification.